# How to use Zorder clustering when writing delta table within PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm trying to write a very large PySpark dataframe, following the advice I see in https://databricks.com/blog/2018/07/31/processing-petabytes-of-data-in-seconds-with-databricks-delta.html

However, this page shows advice in Scala, which I don't know how to translate to PySpark

I see Scala code like this:

```
spark.read.table(connRandom)
     .write.format("delta").saveAsTable(connZorder)

sql(s"OPTIMIZE $connZorder ZORDER BY (src_ip, src_port, dst_ip, dst_port)")
```

but how can I do the equivalent of the second line, say to zorder cluster on a specific column "my_col" in PySpark?

Comment: If I'm writing this to a folder, and not a spark table, is Z-order also applicable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second line is a SQL command given from Scala. You can do the same in python with `spark.sql("OPTIMIZE tableName ZORDER BY (my_col)")`.

Also take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations.html#delta-optimize-python), it has a full notebook example for PySpark.

Comment: Is there a way to write your files already z-ordered? My understanding is that in this way you first write the files and then you z-order them. Wouldn't be faster if they can be directly z-ordered? Obviously just in an overwrite mode.

Comment: Z-order is done only after write. It is not like delta.autoOptimize.optimizeWrite, and instead more like delta.autoOptimize.autoCompact, in the sense that it leads to a new version of the delta table after being performed. https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/table-properties.html